# join two files based on condition in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have 2 different files , one file with Cust# and other with Cusotmer# and names. I want to compare between two files based on the Cust# and pull those records from file2 matching the cust#. I know it's a easy operation in sql, but how to do in Unix. Anyone, any suggestions.. thank you all

file 1:

Cust#

```
1  
2  
3
4
5
```

file2.txt:

Cust#|ad1|ad2|ad3|ad4|name1|name2|name3|loc1|loc2|loc3|city1|city2|city3|st1|st2|st3|st4

```
1|eee|ee|||||||||||city3|st1|st2|st3|st4
8|eee|ee|||||||||||city41|st15|st62|st73|st18
B|eee|ee|||||||||||city32|st51|st52|st53|st88
2|eee|ee|||||||||||city31|st13|st62|st3|st99
3|eee|ee|||||||||||city23|st11|st22|st33|st55
```

output.

```
1|eee|ee|||||||||||city3|st1|st2|st3|st4
2|eee|ee|||||||||||city31|st13|st62|st3|st99
3|eee|ee|||||||||||city23|st11|st22|st33|st55
```

Comment: And what have you tried? It's an easy operation using [join](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) with sort on unix too.

Comment: `awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] > 0'  file1 file2` from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/334450/53084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk :

```
awk -F\| 'NR==FNR{ids[$1]=1;next}ids[$1]==1' file1 file2
```

---

**Edit** - add explanations :

Block after NR==FNR is executed when first file is parsed. It creates an array named 'ids'.
When awk finished to parse first file, array is :

```
ids[1] = 1
ids[2] = 1
ids[3] = 1
ids[4] = 1
ids[5] = 1
```

'next' is called to avoid to execute the rest of the script (when parsing first file)

```
ids[$1]==1
```

will check for each line of the second file if ids[value_inside_first_column] is equal to 1, then prints the line.

This is equivalent to :

```
awk -F\| '
    NR==FNR{
        ids[$1]=1
    }
    NR!=FNR{
        if(ids[$1]==1){
            print $0
        }
    }'
```

---

For fun using grep, but I prefer the awk or join versions :

```
grep -wF -f file1 file2
```

grep solution works on your example but is not stable as it will print lines like this :

```
B|eee|ee||||||1|||||city23|st11|st22|st33|st55
```

Be aware that you have extra spaces characters in your file1 example which leads to unexpected errors.

Comment: right! my file1 begins with a whtespace. . i just removed used a tr

Comment: Hi, in the awk command are we taking the first file using $1 and comparing with file2, indicated by id[$1]=1? that becomes assigning file1 value to 1 right?

Comment: @mac_online Not sure to understand. I edited and added explanations

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
join -t\| -j1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

An alternative using GNU sed:

```
sed 's#.*#/^&|/p#' file1 | sed -f - -n file2
```

Turn the first file into a sed script and use it in a second invocation of sed against file2.

Comment: I don't think `file2` is sorted on the first field... ; )

Comment: @KamilCuk oops! added sorts

Comment: sorting requires alot of memory. I'm getting an error regarding memory shortage